# Are the fusion categories weakly Frobenius?

Tags: ct.category-theory, qa.quantum-algebra, monoidal-categories, fusion-categories

A well-known open problem (generalizing Kaplansky 6th conjecture) asks whether every (spherical) fusion category $\mathcal{C}$ (over $\mathbb{C}$) is of *Frobenius type*, i.e. for every simple object $X$ in $\mathcal{C}$ then $\dim(\mathcal{C})/\dim(X)$ is an algebraic integer.

A (spherical) fusion category $\mathcal{C}$ (over $\mathbb{C}$) will be called *weakly Frobenius* if for every simple object $X$ in $\mathcal{C}$ then there is a positive integer $n$ such that $\dim(\mathcal{C})^n/\dim(X)$ is an algebraic integer (in other words, the ideal generated by $\dim(\mathcal{C})$ is included in the radical of the ideal generated by $\dim(X)$).

**Question**: Are the (spherical) fusion categories (over $\mathbb{C}$) weakly Frobenius?

If so, that would provide a good categorification criterion, because it is not true at the level of fusion rings. For example, consider the following simple integral fusion ring of rank $6$, FPdim $1320$ and type $[1,9,10,11,21,24]$. Its categorification would be pseudo-unitary and spherical (as it is integral), so would not be weakly Frobenius because $7$ is prime factor of $21$ but not of $1320$.

Here are the fusion coefficients:

```
[
[[1,0,0,0,0,0],[0,1,0,0,0,0],[0,0,1,0,0,0],[0,0,0,1,0,0],[0,0,0,0,1,0],[0,0,0,0,0,1]],
[[0,1,0,0,0,0],[1,0,0,1,1,2],[0,0,1,1,1,2],[0,1,1,1,1,2],[0,1,1,1,3,4],[0,2,2,2,4,3]],
[[0,0,1,0,0,0],[0,0,1,1,1,2],[1,1,0,0,2,2],[0,1,0,1,2,2],[0,1,2,2,3,4],[0,2,2,2,4,4]],
[[0,0,0,1,0,0],[0,1,1,1,1,2],[0,1,0,1,2,2],[1,1,1,1,2,2],[0,1,2,2,4,4],[0,2,2,2,4,5]],
[[0,0,0,0,1,0],[0,1,1,1,3,4],[0,1,2,2,3,4],[0,1,2,2,4,4],[1,3,3,4,7,8],[0,4,4,4,8,9]],
[[0,0,0,0,0,1],[0,2,2,2,4,3],[0,2,2,2,4,4],[0,2,2,2,4,5],[0,4,4,4,8,9],[1,3,4,5,9,11]]
]
```

This example is very interesting because it cannot be excluded by a known criterion. It first appeared in [this paper](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=4292959) (Appendix A.2). Idem for the example following the above one in this paper (rank $7$, FPdim $560$ and type $[1,6,7,7,10,10,14]$).